# C/C++ strcmp cannot convert argument 1 from 'char' to 'const char *'

Tags: c++, c, sorting, strcmp

So I'm passing a char Array(En) that consists a few words and I'm trying to sort alphabetically. Unfortunately, my compiler explodes with " int strcmp(const char *,const char *)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'char' to 'const char *" and I'm kinda stuck!

```
void TDihotTable::Set(char *En){
    int i, j;
    bool sorted = false;
    char* pTemp = NULL;
    while (!sorted)
    {
        sorted = true;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < 6 - 1; ++i)
        {
            if (!strcmp(En[i], En[i + 1]) > 0)
            {
                sorted = false;
                pTemp = En[i];
                En[i] = En[i + 1];
                En[i + 1] = pTemp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: C or C++? Pick _one_.

Comment: I found where I was wrong, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function should look more like:

```
void TDihotTable::Set(char **En){
                           ^^
```

That would be a array of pointers to string, which you can strcmp like you done in

```
       if (!strcmp(En[i], En[i + 1]) > 0)
           ^
```

which is als so buggy at the mark.
use

```
       if (strcmp(En[i], En[i + 1]) > 0)
```

at the moment you try to compare single characters.

Answer (score 0):

`strcmp()` expects it's arguments to be of `const char *`, but in your code, `En[i]` and `En[i+1]` are of type `char`.

- if you want to comapre `char`s, use `==` operator.
- if you want to compare *strings*, pass the address using `&En[i]` and `&En[i+1]`

That said,

```
 if (!strcmp(En[i], En[i + 1]) > 0)
```

is wrong. Please verify your logic.

Answer (score 0):

Use `En[i] !=  En[i + 1]` to compare characters. `strcmp` takes `char *` arguments but `En[i]` and `En[i + 1]` are `char`.

Answer (score 0):

`strcmp()` requires strings as arguments for comparison, not chars. So, instead of this line:

```
 if (!strcmp(En[i], En[i + 1]) > 0)
```

You can directly compare the two chars as `if(En[i]==En[i+1])` or `if(En[i]!=En[i+1])` as per your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Array of words is supposed to be a two dimensional array of characters: `char **En`. The comparison should work then.